# Finding out which button was clicked in a SelectedIndexChanged event handler of a GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, event-handling, selectedindexchanged

We have a GridView that contains 2 "Select" buttons for each row that is displayed in the GridView.

We would like to know if there is a way to find out which of the 2 buttons was clicked on by using the SelectedIndexChanged handler.

This coding shows the buttons we have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="UpdatePanelParentsSummary" 
    runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate> 
        <p>Parent Search:
            <asp:TextBox 
                ID="TextBoxSearch" 
                runat="server" 
                Width="207px" 
                Text="ALL"> </asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button 
                ID="ButtonSearch" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Search" />

            <asp:Button 
                ID="ButtonSearchAll" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Show ALL Parents" />

            <br />
        </p>

        <asp:GridView
            ID="GridViewParentsSummary" 
            runat="server" 
            AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID"
            >

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="ID" 
                    HeaderText="ID" 
                    SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherName" 
                    HeaderText="FatherName" 
                    SortExpression="FatherName" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="MotherName" HeaderText="MotherName" 
                    SortExpression="MotherName" />

                <asp:ButtonField 
                    ButtonType="Button" 
                    CommandName="Select" 
                    Text="Select Details" />

                <asp:ButtonField 
                    ButtonType="Button" 
                    CommandName="Select" 
                    Text="New Person To Release Child" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the code in the SelectedIndexChanged handler:

```
Protected Sub GridViewParentsSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndexChanged

    IntParentsID = GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Value

    Response.Redirect("AuthorizationForChildReleaseDetails.aspx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, there is a simple solution to this problem. Your sender is the button clicked. Just try something like:

```
ButtonField buttonClicked = sender as ButtonField;
if (buttonClicked != null) {
    String commandName = buttonClicked.CommandName;

    if (commandName.equals("Command1") {
       ... do something awesome ...
    } else if (commandName.equals("Command2")) {
       ... do something less awesome ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use any property to trigger the switch, I just picked CommandName because it sounded the most intuitive to me.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I will try it out tomorrow and let you know how it works. :-)

Comment: No problem, this is what we do when we wait for answers to our own questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very skilled with vb, but all you really need to do is cast the sender and check the CommandName property in an if statement. Just make sure you set the property value in your aspx file (or whatever file type your display logic uses).

Comment: this shouldn't work, as the sender type is the GridView class....and beware of the commandName, if it's for example : "Select", it will select the actual row, i would recommand using the commandArgument instead, and finaly i would use a Button.OnClick event instead of GridView.SelectedIndexChanged, and use the mGridview.SelectedDataKey("yourKey") to retrieve the key, and the command arg to know witch button you clicked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can differentiate between the source at the GridView event level because it is an event raised by the GridView at that point which is masking the lower level event. You can, however, implement a row level handler to identify which button was used to raise the event and set it up somewhere for use in the gridview event.

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   e.CommandArgument ....contains the argument name 
   ....

}
```